# Does tails work with Mini free Laptops

Tags: security, tails

Does tails work well with mini free laptops. Are there any issues? Such as in proper shutdown.

Can you boot Tails from DVD on mini free?

Can you boot Tails from USB on mini free?

Answer this question only if you are using tails on mini free or have done testing of tails on this laptop.

If you are using an old version of tail or mini free please note this in your answer. 
a

Answer (score 3):

From looking at the pictures on [their website](https://minifree.org/), Minifree laptops appear to be old, re-branded Lenovo T400 and X200 Thinkpads.

If we ignore the fact that they're selling old, presumably ex-business machines with upgraded memory and a nice sticker on the lid, then that's still fairly old hardware. (X200s were [released in 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad_X_Series#X200)... You can pick one up on eBay for a fraction of the cost that they're pedalling them for.)

Having said that, I'm typing this on my old X220 Thinkpad, which is 5 years old, hasn't had a memory upgrade, and can still run the newest version of Tails without any trouble.

The Tails [official requirements page](https://tails.boum.org/doc/about/requirements/index.en.html) says you should be fine on most post-2005 systems with 2GB of memory or more. Which Minifree laptops have.

> Can you boot Tails from DVD on mini free?

Yes, if you burn the image to a DVD.

> Can you boot Tails from USB on mini free?

Yes.